# My in-app purchases are not showing up in by test app on my device (ios)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My in-app purchases are not showing up in my test device.

The status of the purchases are READY-TO-SUBMIT in iTunesConnect.

I selected them from my app page - but the app is not ready to be submitted for release.

Do I have to submit the app for review before I can use the in-app purchases - again just in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

App review is not required to test the In App Purchases in sandbox mode. Just make sure you have done all below things.

1. In App Purchase should be "ON" in capabilities section.
2. App bundle identifier should be same.
3. Product id should be same in the code and in app purchase section.
4. Agreement, tax and Banking info. You need to fill this info for even sandbox mode.

Comment: For  #1 - I've got IN-APP purchase enabled in the app-id on itunes - I created the provision with that app-id. Do I also need to set that in the xcode project file - i.e. the IN-APP purchase capability?

Comment: Yes, add In App Purchase in capabilities.